# DataBinding behavior breaks after navigating back from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

recently I was playing with Android Architecture Component and Data Binding library, and I have been facing a really weird case and after searching through the web and trying different things for days, I decide to come here for help.

I have a fragment in an activity, and I have do `setLifeCycleOwner(fragment)` to the fragment's binding which makes the binding life cycle aware. And there are a checkbox and a button in the fragment, where:
`Checkbox`'s text should be changed based on the check status
`Button` callback starts activity B via `statrActivityForResult`

The problem I am facing is that **when returning from activity B, the checkbox displayed text is not updated anymore.**
I have checked the callback for checkbox (onCheckedChanged), the callback works fine and the model for displaying the text is updated as well. **Somehow the data binding is not receiving the field changed event so the UI is not updated.**

Does anyone have or had this problem problem? or anything I missed checking?
If there's any information that I need to provide, please let me know. Thanks advanced for helping!

---

Here are the examples that involve in the case:

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</layout>
```

**fragment_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="za.co.travelstart.flapp.activities.test.TestViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/section_test"
            bind:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**section_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="za.co.travelstart.flapp.activities.test.TestViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{(compoundButton, isChecked) -> viewModel.onCheckBoxCheckedChanged(isChecked)}"
            android:text="@{viewModel.testModel.checkBoxText}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onButtonClicked()}"
            android:text="Start Test B"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/checkBox" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**TestActivity.kt**

```
class TestActivity : ParentActivity() {

    // View Model
    private lateinit var mViewModel: TestViewModel

    /* ------------------------------- Life Cycle */

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // init view model
        initViewModel()
        // init binding
        initBinding()
        // observe data
        observeData()
        // init fragment utils
        initFragmentUtils()
        // display fragment
        displayFragment()
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int,
                                  resultCode: Int,
                                  data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            1337 -> {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    /* ------------------------------- Methods */

    /**
     * Init view model
     */
    private fun initViewModel() {
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                .of(this)
                .get(TestViewModel::class.java)
    }

    /**
     * Init binding
     */
    private fun initBinding() {
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityTestBinding>(
                this, R.layout.activity_test).apply {
            setLifecycleOwner(this@TestActivity)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Observe the data in view model
     */
    private fun observeData() {
        mViewModel.buttonTriggerLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
            // navigate to test b
            navigateToTestB()
        })
    }

    /**
     * Display test fragment
     */
    private fun displayFragment() {
        fragmentUtils.displayTest()
    }

    /**
     * Navigate to test B
     */
    private fun navigateToTestB() {
        startActivityForResult(Intent(this, TestActivityB::class.java), 1337)
    }
}
```

**TestFragment.kt**

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    // View Model
    private lateinit var mViewModel: TestViewModel

    // Binding
    private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentTestBinding

    /* ------------------------------ Instance Factory */

    companion object {

        /**
         * Instance factory
         */
        fun newInstance() = TestFragment()
    }

    /* ------------------------------ Life Cycle */

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // init view model
        initViewModel()
        // init data binding
        initBinding(inflater, container)
        // return binding root view
        return mBinding.root
    }

    /* ------------------------------ Methods */

    /**
     * Init view model
     */
    private fun initViewModel() {
        activity?.also {
            mViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                    .of(it)
                    .get(TestViewModel::class.java)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Init binding
     */
    private fun initBinding(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                            container: ViewGroup?) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
        mBinding.apply {
            viewModel = mViewModel
            setLifecycleOwner(this@TestFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

**TestViewModel.kt**

```
class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // Data
    val testModel: MutableLiveData<TestModel> = MutableLiveData()

    // Button callback trigger
    val buttonTriggerLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        testModel.value = TestModel()
    }

    /**
     * Callback for checkbox
     */
    fun onCheckBoxCheckedChanged(isChecked: Boolean) {
        testModel.value?.checkBoxText = if (isChecked) "checked" else "unchecked"
    }

    /**
     * Callback for button
     */
    fun onButtonClicked() {
        buttonTriggerLiveData.value = true
    }
}
```

**TestModel.kt**

```
class TestModel : BaseObservable() {
    var checkBoxText = "unclicked"
        @Bindable get() = field
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.checkBoxText)
        }
}
```